# Custom Title Bar Similar to this one

Tags: android, user-interface, titlebar, custom-titlebar

[image]

I want to create a custom title bar, somewhat like this, in my Android app. Please pardon if my question seems idiotic, I'm a beginner. Can anyone tell me if it is a titlebar or an Action bar? Plus how can I give this Shaded Black color to my titlebar/action bar? 
PS: I'm using GingerBread on my Android. My app will require minimum SDK version to be 4 but it targets Jelly bean too. In GingerBread, I can't make use of ActionBars. Please help me with the problem. It would be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the ActionBarSherlock library for this (which will allow you to use this all the way back to SDK version 4).

It is reasonably easy to style, and is for sure the right way to do this.  Lots of examples for this, as it is a very popular library.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: is there any other way to create actionbar-like bar in Android other than Sherlock ActionBar?

Comment: @AbdusSamiKhan you can certainly create it "manually" if you like with a Layout and some Buttons. But you'd have to include it with all of your activities that you want it present for.

Comment: You can create a layout yourself, and there are some alternate libraries for creating a ActionBar - ABS is definitely the best way to do this.

Comment: @Booger I know it's a stupid one to put as a question but can you tell me the hex code for the color of the titlebar in the image?

Comment: That is a gradient.  Just open it in a photo editor and use the color picker to find out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to target min API 4, then as you state you'll be unable to use the ActionBar.

So you could just create your bar as a LinearLayout or something with whatever buttons / icons you want on it and have it at the top of all of your Activities. If you have many of them it would probably be worth it to refactor the Bar (click handlers and such) handling into a subclass of Activity, and then extend that with all of your other activities.

The visual effect could be easily achived with a 9-patch png set as the background of a LinearLayout. Just make the gradient you want in photoshop/Gimp and drop it into draw9Patch to add the pixels on the edge that will allow it to stretch nicely to fit any screen.

**Edit:** using actionbar sherlock as others suggested is probably a better idea than doing it "manually" as I suggested.